# Terraform RKE provider vs rancher2 provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, rancher, rke

I am new to terraform.
Now we are planning to use terraform to rebuild our infrastrucure on AWS.
We are running kubernetes clusters managed with rancher on AWS.
We have one k8s cluster that was built with RKE, which also hosts rancher, and a couple of other kubernetes clusters that was created by rancher.

There are two external modules that might be helpful: RKE provider and rancher2 provider.

The goal is to manage everything with terraform. I can build a kubernetes cluster with terraform RKE provider. My question is how do I install rancher on it, and how do I use rancher to create other k8s clusters in teraform?

Answer (score 0):

RKE and rancher are two different things.

> One common misconception among new users is that RKE will install Rancher for you. While Rancher uses RKE under the hood, RKE can also be used to create Kubernetes clusters as a standalone piece of software.

Reference: https://rancher.com/blog/2019/2019-02-04-rancher-vs-rke/